# Why add S0 -> S while converting CFG to Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: normal-forms

While converting CFG to CNF sometimes it is suggested to add extra step.
Add new start symbol **S0** and add new derivation **S0 -> S**. Book Hopcroft Ullman does not suggest this step but many other articles suggest to add this step.
What is purpose of adding this extra derivation?

Comment: I could not found explanation for this anywhere... even on this platform. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the fact that grammars in Chomsky normal form cannot generate the empty word. Indeed, if we only allow rules of the form $A \to BC$ and $A \to a$, then it is impossible to generate the empty word.

In order to accommodate languages containing the empty word, we allow the transition $S \to \epsilon$, where $S$ is the starting symbol. For various reasons (for example, the proof of the pumping lemma), we still don't want any other symbol to generate the empty word, so we disallow $S$ on the right-hand side.

The transition $S_0 \to S$ allows us to treat $S$ as a normal symbol, that is, to allow it to appear on the right-hand side, even if the grammar generates the empty word.

Comment: while we convert CFG to CNF "removing ϵ productions" is one of the steps. We can remove ϵ production without adding   S0→S; and it is already understood that when CFG is converted to CNF, resultant grammar will not have ϵ (empty word)

Comment: I have to disagree with your claim that when a CFG is converted to CNF, it is understood that the resultant grammar will not generate $\epsilon$. It depends on the definition. Your definition doesn't allow generating $\epsilon$. Other definitions do allow it.

Comment: Referring from Hopcroft Ullman : 
Theorem:
 If G is a CFG whose language contains at least one string other than  ϵ   then there is a grammar G'  in Chomsky Normal Form  such that
L(G) = L(G') - { ϵ }

Comment: We’re talking past each other. Some definitions don’t allow the empty word. Others do. In the latter case, you need the additional production you are concerned about.

Comment: Reiterating: Hopcroft and Ullman’s book is not scripture. Other books could use slightly different definitions, and it wouldn’t be considered blasphemous.

Comment: I think I need to clarify my understanding first. Thanks for the quick responses.